# How to determine which diode conducts in diode-OR application

Tags: diodes, electrical

Say I have two 12V power sources - 12V_A and 12V_B. What happens in the following scenarios:

1. If 12_A = 12_B = 12V. Do both diodes conduct?
2. If 12_A is slightly higher than 12V_B. Does the top diode conduct? Or both?
3. If 12_A = 12V and 12V_B = 0. We know that top diode conducts for sure, but is there also leakage through the bottom diode?

[image]

Comment: 1. Yes, 2 yes and depends what slightly means 3. yes

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand diodes are resistors that change value depending on the voltage across them.

You should be familiar with the voltage current relationship of a diode.

[image]

But if you take that graph and plot the slope versus the voltage, you get V/I which is the resistance vs voltage graph, you are likely less familiar with and looks something like this.

[image]

So, having that in mind, lets look at your cases.

In case 1, if they are matched diodes, they will both have the same voltage across them and will both conduct equally. In reality they will differ and whichever diode has the smaller threshold voltage will conduct a lot more.

In case 2, the top diode will have the higher voltage across it and will conduct more than the bottom one. What the bottom one does depends on your definition of slightly. If the right side of the diode is lower voltage than the left it will still conduct but at a higher resistance. If the voltage is reversed it will leak a bit.

In case 3, obviously the top diode is conducting, the bottom diode will either present a large resistance and leak some current back to the left, or the voltage will exceed the reverse breakdown voltage and it will conduct back to the left and pull down the output.

Comment: At your second graph, let's see if I can remember the fuzz... does diodes break ohm's law. Yeah, let's remember those fun times.

Answer (score 1):

We can represent your two input voltage sources as:

$$V_A = 12$$
$$V_B = 12 + V_{\text{offset}}$$

We can then sweep over the value of the offset voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkPGXv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think exploring this visually using a quick simulation is a good way to get an overall feel for what's going on, with the offset voltage on the x-axis, and the currents through each diode on the y-axis:

[image: Current through two diodes with offset voltage]

There is a region where both diodes are conducting, and there are regions beyond that where one or the other is basically off.

In reality, the size of these regions will depend on the diodes and the current level. Even two same-part-number-diodes may not show the current intersection at exactly zero offset voltage due to manufacturing variances.

Your third question could be answered by setting $$V_{\text{offset}}=-12$$ but I think you can largely extrapolate that behavior from the graph above.

Answer (score 0):

> If 12_A = 12_B = 12.00 V. Do both diodes conduct?

Partially yes. They would share the current drawn if both diodes had equal Vdrop values, but that is rare. Most likely one diode will dominate the current flow.

> If 12_A is slightly higher than 12V_B. Does the top diode conduct? Or both?

Yes, even if slightly higher that diode will dominate the current flow.

> If 12_A = 12V and 12V_B = 0. We know that top diode conducts for sure, but is there also leakage through the bottom diode?

Under condition where the input (anode) is at ground potential schottky diodes have a higher leakage current than most. If driven by a PNP collector than there is no leakage current.

Note that my answers assume a current drain of 1 mA or more. At low uA levels the diodes may not 'turn ON' properly.

Answer (score 0):

To first order, diodes conduct if they voltage across them exceeds the threshold voltage (somewhere around 0.4V for the Schottkey diodes shown).

That approximation breaks for some of your questions, because the "threshold" isn't an on/off switch - it's a fast exponential rise, and it varies slightly from diode to diode.

So:
1) A = 12V, B = 12V, Output = (12-0.4 = 11.6V)
Here, both diodes will conduct.  The voltages across them are equal but, because of part to part variation, one may still conduct significantly more than the other (or, they may be close to equal)

2) A > 12V, B = 12V.  Depending on what you mean by "slightly" higher, either A or B could conduct more if the "slightly higher" voltage is still within the part to part variation of the diodes.  If by "slightly higher" you mean, say, 0.1V higher, A will conduct much more than B.  If A is only 1mV higher than B, you're within the part to part variation and either diode could be conducting more.

3) A = 12V, B = 0V, Out = 11.6V.  Yes, there is reverse leakage through B.  If your diode is, say, [this one](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZLLS350.pdf), you will get about 0.05uA of reverse leakage.  There will definitely not be any current in the forward direction through B.

Answer (score 0):

RE: your 2nd & 3rd questions only.  (1st should be obvious, yes but rarely perfectly equal due to mfg tolerances if mixed batches.)

Here is an example of 2 Schottky power diodes rated for 0.305V @ 1A, so they have much more leakage than small signal diodes and even more than Silicon diodes.

I made an artificial slightly smaller voltage of 0.1V between the diodes.

The [Falstad simulated](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.634267539816555%2050%202%2050%0AR%20288%20208%20240%20208%200%203%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Ad%20288%20208%20368%20208%201%200.305904783%0Ag%20368%20240%20368%20272%200%0Ar%20368%20208%20368%20240%200%2010%0Ad%20288%20160%20368%20160%201%200.305904783%0Av%20288%20160%20288%20208%200%200%2040%200.1%200%200%200.5%0Ax%20223%20170%20272%20173%204%2024%200.1V%0Aw%20368%20160%20368%20208%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%204354%2020%200.2%200%202%200%203%20Power%20source%0Ao%204%2064%200%204353%200.0001%200.2915613982693648%201%202%204%203%20Upper%20Diode%0Ao%201%2064%200%2012545%200.0001%201.0235093471445877%201%202%201%203%20Lower%20Diode%0Ao%203%2064%200%204353%205%201.6%202%202%203%203%0A) scope traces here display the max,min values of each signal.
The power sources has 0 ohms.

What differences in current do you see for forward and reverse?

Does it make sense? Have you researched the Early Effect yet? or seen the  ΔV/ΔI=Rs( or ESR) slope of diodes in datasheets?  Any questions?

[image]